# SIMICS - Installation of SIMICS on Windows with German language fails

Tags: simics

The installation of SIMICS 2023.31 on Windows with German Language fails.

Because the installer calls "check-folder-permissions.cmd", this calls "icacls.exe" and "findstr.exe". The ""icacls.exe" creates the file "current_permissions.log" and "findstr.exe" search in this file the string "Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files". But "icacls.exe" writes the german text of this string "1 Dateien erfolgreich verarbeitet, bei 0 Dateien ist ein Verarbeitungsfehler aufgetreten.". Therefore "check-folder-permissions.cmd" fails and therefore the installation fails.

The installer should also support other languages than english.

Answer (score 3):

Currently ISPM only supports English.

Intel has an internal feature request to add language support but I have not ETA.