# Install Simics with intel-simics-package-manager-1.7.5-win64.exe failed

Tags: simics

I want to install the latest Simics version with `intel-simics-package-manager-1.7.5-win64.exe`, but failed. The error messages is

```
Secure folder permissions could not be set for C:\Program Files\Intel Simics Package Manager. The installer will now attempt to reinstall theapplication as an administrator.
```

I tried to use another directory to install, run as administrator, change the owner of the directory, the installer still complains this error.

My OS is Windows 11 23H2 (22631.3007)

Is there any workaround I can do?

[image]

Comment: What locale/language or region is your Windows system set to?

Comment: I ask because I suspect this is the same symptom that was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496479/simics-installation-of-simics-on-windows-with-german-language-fails where the installer fails to find the english text in a script, and fails the installation.

Comment: @BradP. Mine is Chinese, I'll try to switch to English, thank you very much for your tips!

Comment: @BradP. Switch to English resolved my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: To allow the question to be closed: this seems to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496479/simics-installation-of-simics-on-windows-with-german-language-fails